How to find openSSL's AES T-table location for cache side channel attack
Let us assume I have a physically-indexed last-level cache, which is shared between the victim and adversary. Both the victim and attacker have their own copy of openSSL library in the caches. Victim has activated the cache randomization technique. Attacker wants to steal the victim's AES key using cache-based side-channel attacks such as prime-probe.
Question - How will an attacker find the victim's target address i.e. the location where the victim's T-table is located? I am not concerned with the eviction set discovery. The question is how will an attacker find the target address?

This is a hard subject, it is called co-location. In general, we assume we are co-located. Then the cache attack is executed. If you don't know where is your target is located, you need to jump at least half of the possible positions..
